# vector graphic in wpf xaml is visible outside of window frame

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, xaml, vector

I try to have a vector graphic in my c#-WPF project.

My problem is :

My graphic (created by illustrator and export to XAML) is bigger than my window size and because of that my vector graphic is still visible outside of window frame (in border aria).

how can i limit it in a container ?

This is a simple example of a graphic in my costume window :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="319" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"  
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    AllowsTransparency="true" Background ="Transparent"
    Topmost="True"
    WindowStyle="None"  ShowInTaskbar="False" Height="453.487"  >
    <Window.Resources>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="#dcdfe1" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="border" Background="white">
        <Border.Effect >
            <DropShadowEffect x:Name="DropShadowEffect" BlurRadius="10" Color="Black" RenderingBias="Quality"  ShadowDepth="0"  Opacity="0.6"/>
        </Border.Effect>
        <Grid >
            <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>





            <Grid.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.44"/>
                <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="1"/>

            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Grid.Background>
        <Path Grid.RowSpan="4" Data="M20,202 C20,202 583,167 607,197" Margin="10,46.447,0,-218" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Row="1">
            <Path.Fill>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                    <GradientStop Offset="1"/>
                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Path.Fill>
        </Path>





            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="30" Background="#dcdfe1"  Name="titleBar"  >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
           </Grid>



            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"  Orientation="Vertical" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
        <Grid Grid.Row="5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=" auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=" auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Width="60"  Grid.Column="2" Content="close" Margin="5"   Name="btn_ok" Click="btn_ok_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Border>
</Window>
```

[image: this is result of my sample code]

thanks for your help .

Comment: Try to set ClipToBound="True" for the Grid. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.uielement.cliptobounds%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396

Comment: You are setting negative bottom margin.

Comment: You shouldn't use margin to position things like that. Don't drag stuff round in the designer. It'll all turn into a big mess before you know it.  Also.  Everything is inside a border and you set a dropshadow on that border which means everything will be blurred. Bitmap effects apply to everything inside their element. You should have the border in a grid and everything else in the grid, but not in the border. Unless you like blurred text.

Comment: thank you  Andrii Nikolaienko,   ClipToBounds works perfectly

Comment: How can i mark a Comment as Accepted answer when you answer the Question in comments ? Andrii

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thank you [Andrii Nikolaienko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8385666/andrii-nikolaienko). I set ClipToBounds="True"  and it works perfectly.

```
<Grid ClipToBounds="True">
```

Thank you [andy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/426185/andy) for your advice. I edit my xaml file like this is it ok ?

```
   <Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.MainWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    Width="319" 
    WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen"  
    ResizeMode="NoResize"
    AllowsTransparency="true" Background ="Transparent"
    Topmost="True"
    WindowStyle="None"  ShowInTaskbar="False" Height="453.487"  >
    <Window.Resources>
    </Window.Resources>
    <Grid Margin="10"  >
        <Grid.Effect >
            <DropShadowEffect x:Name="DropShadowEffect" BlurRadius="10" Color="Black" RenderingBias="Quality"  ShadowDepth="0"  Opacity="0.6"/>
        </Grid.Effect>
        <Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="#dcdfe1" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="border" Background="Red" ></Border>
        <Grid ClipToBounds="True">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions >
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>

            <Grid.Background>
                <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                    <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0.44"/>
                    <GradientStop Color="Orange" Offset="1"/>

                </LinearGradientBrush>
            </Grid.Background>
            <Path Grid.RowSpan="4" Data="M20,202 C20,202 583,167 607,197" Margin="10,46.447,0,-218" Stretch="Fill" Grid.Row="1">
                <Path.Fill>
                    <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="0.5,1" StartPoint="0.5,0">
                        <GradientStop Color="White" Offset="0"/>
                        <GradientStop Offset="1"/>
                    </LinearGradientBrush>
                </Path.Fill>
            </Path>

            <Grid Grid.ColumnSpan="2" Height="30" Background="#dcdfe1"  Name="titleBar"  >
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="*"/>
                    <ColumnDefinition  Width="auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            </Grid>



            <StackPanel Grid.Row="2"  Orientation="Vertical" FlowDirection="LeftToRight"/>
            <Grid Grid.Row="5">
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                    <ColumnDefinition />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=" auto" />
                    <ColumnDefinition Width=" auto"/>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <Button Width="60"  Grid.Column="2" Content="close" Margin="5"   Name="btn_ok" Click="btn_ok_Click" />
            </Grid>
        </Grid>
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 1):

Your immediate problem is caused by the bitmap effect you're applying to the border.
You should not put the border around everything like that, because everything inside it has the bitmap effect applied.
Move the border:

```
<Grid >
        <Grid.RowDefinitions >
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
            <RowDefinition Height="auto"/>
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Border Grid.RowSpan="5" Margin="10" BorderBrush="#dcdfe1" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="border" Background="white">
        <Border.Effect >
            <DropShadowEffect x:Name="DropShadowEffect" BlurRadius="10" Color="Black" RenderingBias="Quality"  ShadowDepth="0"  Opacity="0.6"/>
        </Border.Effect>
    </Border>
```

This will also allow the grid to clip.
I'm not at all clear what your intention is with this, maybe the grid should have a margin or something.

Answer (score 0):

It is being caused by your border value of 10 in all directions:

```
<Border Margin="10" BorderBrush="#dcdfe1" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="border" Background="white">
```

I think you need to use this to remove the over spill of your vector graphic at the bottom of your window:

```
<Border Margin="10,10,10,0" BorderBrush="#dcdfe1" BorderThickness="1" x:Name="border" Background="white">
```

Comment: No it isn't. The problem is due to how bitmap effects work.